# Ошибка cv2 Python веб-камера

Tags: python, cv2

При обычном выводе камеры возникает ошибка, код полностью правильный и раньше работал, что делать?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Тут скрин ошибки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ошибка скорее всего возникает когда ты передаёшь пустое изображение. Скорее всего кадры из твоей камеры не были захвачены. Это означает, то что соединиться с камерой не удалось или соединение настроено неправильно.

1. Перепроверь правильно ли ты подключил камеру
2. Не повреждён ли usb-port
3. Доступна ли камера в "Диспетчер устройств".

Рекомендую вам разобраться верно ли вы указали индекс камеры?
У вас может быть подключено другое устройство к вашему ПК, которое не является камерой, но OpenCV будет считать его как камеру (Такое бывает). Поэтому переберите все индексы в вашем коде.

```
   Вот здесь => cv2.VideoCapture()
```

Ниже я прикрепил ссылки можете с ними ознакомиться.

[OpenCV tutorial with camera](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

[OpenCV VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1)